# How to create a custom button in Android that animates with a frame animation

Tags: android, animation, button

Is it possible to create a custom button in Android, where the button is idly animating using a frame animation (AnimationDrawable)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation

- create the frame animation
- save it in the res/drawable folder
- ser the button background to be that resource
- getBackground.start()